# On mouse hover show a div like jQuery Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let consider fallowing scenario

```
 <p>jhony</p>
 <p>ram</p>
 <p>lilly</p>

 <div id="about"></div>

 <script>
      $(function() {
          $('p').hover(function() { 
             $('#about').show(); 
               }, function() { 
                   $('#about').hide(); 
        });
     });
```

Know on mouse hover on the p tag a div will showed,But it is taking always a fixed/absolute position,But I want to show it with respect to hovering element.

Example:

If I place mouse on 'jhony' then about div should be shown left to it,
If I place mouse on 'ram' then about div should be shown left to it,
If I place mouse on 'lilly' then about div should be shown left to it.

Finally it should work like jQuery Tooltip.

Comment: and why you don't use jQuery tooltip?

Comment: Look at this [example](http://api.jquery.com/hover), there is tooltip displays on the right side of the item.

Comment: Please look at the Jquery site there is so much info you can find there

Comment: Check this , same question


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254569/how-to-create-a-tooltip-with-jquery-without-a-plugin/1254637#1254637

Comment: use offset.top for that.

Comment: @DonovanCharpin here I want to show a div on mouse over,Can i achieve it using Tooltip

Answer (score 3):

Why u use jQuery for it? U can use only css

`p:hover span{display : block}`

or if you want use jQuery/js you must calculate height from top of window to your p and set it for your div:
`$(function() {
          $('p').hover(function() { $('#about').css('top',this.offset().top
)}`