# Make Bootstrap's tooltips hoverable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, hover, tooltip

Bootstrap's tooltips closes once you try to hover it, which sucks in case you want to put a link on it.

See fiddle:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/YTb62/16/

Code:

```
<span class="x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-title="It works?" data-content="If you can <a href='http://youtu.be/IBH4g_ua5es'>click me</a>, it works.">Hover me</span>

<script>
    $(function() {
         $('.x').popover({
                placement: 'right',
                trigger: 'hover'
             });
    });
</script>
```

PS: Any way to use bootstrap tooltips along with [HoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see a way to do it because Bootstrap's hover code removes the tooltip element from the DOM the instant you move off the `<span>` tag, so there is nothing for the user to click on.

Have you thought of creating your own tooltips? Then you could build-in that feature, possibly by building-in a delay before removing the tooltip from the DOM. To build-in the delay, perhaps check out the [setTimeout()](http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval) method.

[How to create a tooltip with jquery without a plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254569/how-to-create-a-tooltip-with-jquery-without-a-plugin)

http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-tooltips-create-your-own-tooltip-plugin/

http://www.queness.com/post/92/create-a-simple-cssjavascript-tooltip-with-jquery

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/you-still-cant-create-a-jquery-plugin/

http://www.davidjrush.com/blog/2011/12/simple-jquery-tooltip/